# "Power off" motion detector

Tags: motion-sensor

Is there an exterior motion detector that turns power off instead of on when someone enters a space? All internet inquiries have only found power on detectors. I've also found "light curtains" but they are overkill and too pricey.

Comment: Seems counterintuitive. What is the use?

Comment: You can use a relay to achieve this with any detector.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic Rewording to how can I make a motion detector turn off the lights with a relay would be ok.

Comment: @HebrewHammer maybe he's watching *something* on his computer and wants to kill the screen if someone wanders by :-)

Comment: @EdBeal I think it's worded alright - he asks if there exists a product, not for specific recommendations. I'd also like to buy something but am not sure how to search for one. 

I need one so my indoor grow lights will turn off when my cat wanders in to munch on grass - the lights are really bright...

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy with a relay:

[image]

Just be sure to size the relay appropriately for your load (I used a light but it could be anything).